# How to use cmake to compile both C++ file and CUDA file

Tags: c++, cmake, cuda, nvcc

I know how to use cmake to compile C++ file with cuda function like cublas. However, in my project, there is a kernel function that I write by myself. I see the g++ compiler do not know how to deal with the kernel<<<,>>>. Could you please help me fix this problem? The following is the CMakeLists that I used to compile the C++ files with cublas.

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "-g")
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

project(GPU_LMM)
find_package(GSL REQUIRED)
find_package(BLAS REQUIRED)
find_package(CUDA)
if (CUDA_FOUND)
    message("CUDA found")
else()
    message("CUDA not found, doing something alternatively")
endif()

include_directories(test_cuda PRIVARE
                ${GSL_INCLUDE_DIRS}
                ${BLAS_INCLUDE_DIRS}
                ${CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS}
                ${CUDA_CUBLAS_DIRS}
                                    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})

add_executable(GPU_LMM main.cpp aux.cpp)
target_link_libraries( GPU_LMM  PRIVATE
                    ${GSL_LIBRARY}
                    ${BLAS_LIBRARIES}
                    ${CUDA_LIBRARIES}
                    ${CUDA_CUBLAS_LIBRARIES})
```

I have three files to compile as the following.

```
main.cpp aux.cpp aux.hpp
```

The aux.cpp contains the cuda kernel function.
Thank your everybody!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have cuda kernels that have to be compiled with `nvcc`, their extension should be `.cu`, no `.cpp` (so that should be `aux.cu`). Then cmake will use the proper compiler for the proper file.

Since cmake 3.10.0, CUDA support is even native, you just need to activate the language.